# How to Use Singular/Plural in this Respectively statement?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am thinking which statement is correct. 
Statement 1

```
Cat and Human has four and two legs, respectively.
```

Statement 2

```
Cat and Human have four and two legs, respectively.
```

Comment: Since both are capitalized one could read it as referring to a cat named Cat and a human called Human. In that case the second statement is correct. Otherwise use @wythagoras answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these sentences are correct. A correct sentence would be

> Cats and humans have four and two legs, respectively.

"cat" and "human" should be plural here. Also, there is no reason to capitalize "human" in the middle of an sentence.

Comment: Can you guide on similar problem [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342349/respectively-not-in-the-end-of-the-sentence) to use respectively not in the end of the sentence. How to do it?